# Estimation: An integral from MIT Integration bee 2022 (QF)

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

We need to determine the value of:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n\cdot \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} (1-3x^2+x^4)^n\mathrm{d}x$$

Since a limit has been given, one suspects that, as usual, the integral is not easy to evaluate in general and some estimates have to be made. Some promising starts (and observations) include:

1. The polynomial always lies between $5/16$ and $1$ in the given range. Perhaps we can ignore some higher order terms (even $x$ has modulus less than one)? But the problem is that *exponent* $n$.
2. Reduction formula and integration by parts can give a recursion. But all reasonable ways of splitting the integrand seem to complicate matters rather than simplify them.
3. We can now take some hints from the limits. Perhaps some trigonometric substitution can aid. A reasonable one is $x^2=\frac 14\sin \theta$ or $x=\frac 12 \cos\theta$ but there is not much one can do due to the quadratic polynomial.
4. Factorize the polynomial as $x^2-3x+1$ has all real roots? But I still get stuck.

But I am unable to make any of these work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change variables to $u = \sqrt{n} x$.  Then you have

$$\sqrt{n} \int_{-\sqrt{n}/2}^{\sqrt{n}/2} \left( 1 - {3u^2 \over n} + {u^4 \over n^2} \right)^n {1 \over \sqrt{n}} \: du$$

The $\sqrt{n}$ cancels, leaving

$$\int_{-\sqrt{n}/2}^{\sqrt{n}/2} \left( 1 - {3u^2 \over n} + {u^4 \over n^2} \right)^n \: du$$

Now as $n \to \infty$ the integrand approaches $\exp(-3u^2)$ so you can use the Gaussian integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \: dx = \sqrt{\pi}$ to get the answer.

This is an example of [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) for approximating integrals.

Comment: You use dominated convergence but you haven't shown that the integrands are, in fact, dominated!

Answer (score 7):

Use the substitution $x\leftrightarrow \sqrt{n}x$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}}^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}} \left(1 - \frac{3x^2}{n}+\frac{x^4}{n^2}\right)^ndx \longrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-3x^2}\:dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}$$

by dominated convergence.

Comment: That's really neat!

Comment: This answer is incomplete because it does not show that the integrands are uniformly dominated by a $L^1$ function!

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch an exercise for OP, I should not provide a full proof. There are many such "incomplete" answers on this site, you are just being too much of a pedant. It is better to be a more positive user. For example, you could have suggested a dominating function in your critique. Your comment required no effort to produce.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm at it, no need to be insulted by my comment, which was not its intention. (the downvote is because you did not highlight the need to provide a dominating function, which can lead to confusion for people who are not familiar with the DCT). (And furthermore I encourage you to improve also the incomplete answers you cite, as it would improve the overall quality of this site!)

Comment: I have written an answer here that is supposed to fill the gap in your answer mentioned above, it is about half an hour of work but might be useful for students learning about the DCT (while I agree that it is didactically not good to be pedantic, I think it is still very useful and vital to not sweep important details under the rug ): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4627161/631742 Would be great if you could verify my work! Thanks in advance and cheers, Maximilian

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch If you think answers on MSE must provide all the reasons behind them then I'm afraid you're going to downvote a lot on this site. Someone with more reputation than me should understand that. A lot of us don't need every step to be justified because we can fill in the blanks for ourselves.

Comment: @Accelerator The answer by Ninad was good, but it would have been better if he said one sentence about the $L^1$ issue (I am happy to upvote if one sentence about this is edited in). Of my around $3500$ votes cast about $160$ are downvotes. Maybe I was a bit harsh here, but I am keen on the $L^1$ issue not just because it is a detail left out, but because people not familiar with the DCT may pick up the bad habit of forgetting to check the $L^1$ condition, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 3):

The other two answers have illustrated very nicely how the Dominated Convergence Theorem can be used to simplify very elegantly the limit in question.

However, both answers are incomplete as they do not show that application of the Dominated Convergence Theorem is justified in this case, i.e. they have not shown that the supremum of the absolute values of the integrands is integrable. This incompleteness can lead to confusion for readers that are not familiar with the DCT.

One might leave the proof that the supremum of the integrands is in $L^1$ as an exercise to the reader (which was unfortunately not done in either of the answers). Since there are some annoying calculations to be made, my answer will solve this exercise by showing that application of the DCT (and also the monotone convergence Theorem!) is justified.

---

Since

$$\int_{-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}}^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}} \left(1 - \frac{3x^2}{n}+\frac{x^4}{n^2}\right)^n\,\mathrm dx = 2\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}}  \left(1 - \frac{3x^2}{n}+\frac{x^4}{n^2}\right)^n\,\mathrm dx,$$ the integrands in question are
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}f_n:[0,\infty)&\to\mathbb R_+,\\x&\mapsto \left(1 - \frac{3x^2}{n}+\frac{x^4}{n^2}\right)^n [x\le \sqrt n/2],\end{split}\end{equation*}

where I am using Iverson brackets for my notation. I claim that the $f_n$ are an increasing sequence of functions, so that they are dominated by $x\mapsto \exp(-3x^2)$ (and alternatively one could also apply the monotone convergence Theorem without needing to invoke the DCT).

Fix $x\in(0,\infty)$. We calculate
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial n}f_n(x) = \left(\frac{x^4}{n^2}-\frac{3 x^2}{n}+1\right)^n \left(\ln \left(\frac{x^4}{n^2}-\frac{3
   x^2}{n}+1\right)+\frac{n \left(\frac{3 x^2}{n^2}-\frac{2 x^4}{n^3}\right)}{\frac{x^4}{n^2}-\frac{3
   x^2}{n}+1}\right).$$

I claim that $\frac{\partial}{\partial n}f_n(x)\ge 0$ when $x\in(0,\sqrt n/2)$, for which it is enough to show that
$$\ln \left(\frac{x^4}{n^2}-\frac{3
   x^2}{n}+1\right)+\frac{n \left(\frac{3 x^2}{n^2}-\frac{2 x^4}{n^3}\right)}{\frac{x^4}{n^2}-\frac{3
   x^2}{n}+1}\ge 0.$$

Set $y = \frac{x}{\sqrt n}$, then we need to show that

$$g(y)\overset{\text{Def.}}=\frac{3 y^2-2 y^4}{y^4-3 y^2+1}+\log \left(y^4-3 y^2+1\right)\ge 0$$ for all $y\in[0,1/2]$.

But $$g'(y) = \frac{2 y^3 \left(2 y^4-6 y^2+7\right)}{\left(y^4-3 y^2+1\right)^2}$$ is $\ge 0$ for all $y\in(0,1/2)$, therefore we infer from $g(0)=0$ that $g(y)\ge 0$ for all $y\in[0,1/2]$.

It follows that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial n}f_n(x)\ge 0$$ for all $x\in(0,\sqrt n/2)$.

Since $n\mapsto [0\le x\le \sqrt n/2]$ is increasing for all fixed $x\in\mathbb R_+$, it follows that $n\mapsto f_n(x)$ is increasing for all $x\in\mathbb R_+$. Thus we can apply DCT or the monotone convergence Theorem, as claimed.

Comment: I appreciate this post! There is a reason why the most upvoted post was not selected ;) [although I must admit I had not heard the name of the theorem prior the OP]